Force (Resharper?) code format to allow all method parameters on single (but new) line
I updated ReSharper yesterday to version 2024.3.20241113.1046. Now I get tons of formatting errors.
I looked through all of the resharper code format options, but I cannot figure out how to tell resharper, that it is okay if all parameters are on a single but new line:

Despite the coincidence with the update of resharper, I am not quite sure, if an option in resharper changed, or if resharper changed the way it reads its configuration from other files.
It says:

So maybe I would have to change a setting in another file?

Check the Resharper settings: C# -> Formatting Style -> Line Breaks and Wrapping -> Arrangement of method signatures -> Max formal parameters on a single line. I have that set to 10,000.

Yes, I have set that to 10,000 too.

I was facing this issue, too. What helped me was removing all obj and bin directories (IDE must be closed) using PowerShell: dir .\ -include bin,obj* -recurse | foreach($_) { rd $_.fullname -Recurse -Force}
